# Create Validator wrapper tag

Tags: jakarta-ee, bean-validation, custom-validators

I created the custom validator tag which wrap @Pattern.

Here,

```
@Pattern(regexp = "～")
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface CustomConstraint {

    String message() default "";
    Class[] groups() default {};
    Class[] payload() default {};
}
```

But, this tag has the problem which cannot set the attribute of "message".
How I set the attribute of "message"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `@OverridesAttribute`:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "～")
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface CustomConstraint {

    String message() default "";
    Class[] groups() default {};
    Class[] payload() default {};

    @OverridesAttribute(constraint = Pattern.class, name = "message")
    String patternMessage() default "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Hardy. I comfirmed the same thing by ＠ReportAsSingleViolation.　What is the difference between ＠OverridesAttribute and ＠ReportAsSingleViolation?

Comment: ＠ReportAsSingleViolation will just report a single constraint violation, the one form the composed constraint class, even if there are multiple violations. Without ＠ReportAsSingleViolation  you get one message for each failing constraint of the composed constraint. In the latter cases you can then use ＠OverridesAttribute to override message keys of the composing constraints (like Pattern in your case).

Comment: I try to use ＠overridesattribute